# Flask 1.1.2 Error in app: Exception on / [GET]

Tags: python, flask

This is my code:

```
import redis, sqlite3, time
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, g, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

conn = sqlite3.connect('trade.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signals (
        timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        ticker,
        order_action,
        order_contracts,
        order_price
    )
""")
conn.commit()

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect('trade.db')
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def dashboard():
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM signals
    """)
    signals = cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template('dashboard.html', signals=signals)

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    data = request.data

    if data:
        r.publish('tradingview', data)

        data_dict = request.json

        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO signals (ticker, order_action, order_contracts, order_price) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        """, (data_dict['ticker'], 
                data_dict['strategy']['order_action'], 
                data_dict['strategy']['order_contracts'],
                data_dict['strategy']['order_price']))

        db.commit()

        return data

    return {
        "code": "success"
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Error that comes out:

```
[2021-08-10 18:28:56,098] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback [2021-08-10 18:28:56,098] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\Desktop\API TWS\TradingView IB Integration\webapp.py", line 37, in dashboard
    return render_template('dashboard.html', signals=signals)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\EQUIPO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: dashboard.html
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2021 18:28:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: https://overiq.com/flask-101/templates-in-flask/ Check if `template_folder` exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is in your templates folder location. Do you have a folder structure where the templates folder is on the same level as  your flask app. You can try copying a template I have here:
https://github.com/shoryamalani/templates/tree/master/flask/flask-normal
Hope this helps. Please also tell me if this solution works or if you get a new error.